# How can I transfer to a "tableau" format in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

Is there an easy way to transfer to a tableau format(only keeps the parent level once)? I understand that the target format is not good in data science. But it makes the report easy to read. I can easily write it to excel and send the report to my boss..

```
library(data.table)
(dt <- data.table(Parent_Product=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                 Sub_Product=c("red","red","blue","yellow","pink","pink"),
                 Sub_Product1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 Value=c(100,200,300,400,500,600)))

#>    Parent_Product Sub_Product Sub_Product1 Value
#> 1:              A         red            1   100
#> 2:              A         red            2   200
#> 3:              A        blue            3   300
#> 4:              B      yellow            4   400
#> 5:              B        pink            5   500
#> 6:              B        pink            6   600

(target_dt <- data.table(Parent_Product=c("A",NA,NA,"B",NA,NA),
                        Sub_Product=c("red",NA,"blue","yellow","pink",NA),
                        Sub_Product1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                        Value=c(100,200,300,400,500,600)))

#>    Parent_Product Sub_Product Sub_Product1 Value
#> 1:              A         red            1   100
#> 2:           <NA>        <NA>            2   200
#> 3:           <NA>        blue            3   300
#> 4:              B      yellow            4   400
#> 5:           <NA>        pink            5   500
#> 6:           <NA>        <NA>            6   600
```

Comment: `dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x){x[duplicated(x)] <- NA; x})]` gets you there in this case, though it's naive across grouping columns

Comment: @alistaire `duplicated()` fails if a `Sub_product` apears again further down below another `Parent_Product`. Let's envision a `Parent_Product` "C" with `Sub_Product` "red".

Comment: Yeah, doing it grouped is more robust: `dt[duplicated(Sub_Product), Sub_Product := NA_character_, by = Parent_Product][duplicated(Parent_Product), Parent_Product := NA_character_][]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be consolidated into fewer steps, but at least this is transparent what's going on at each step:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Parent_Product=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                  Sub_Product=c("red","red","blue","yellow","pink","pink"),
                  Sub_Product1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                  Value=c(100,200,300,400,500,600))


#create index 1:.N by Parent Product
dt[, idx_Parent := 1:.N, by = .(Parent_Product)]
#ditto for combo of parent product and sub product
dt[, idx_Sub := 1:.N, by = .(Parent_Product, Sub_Product)]
#Update idx > 1 to NA
dt[idx_Parent > 1, Parent_Product := NA]
dt[idx_Sub > 1, Sub_Product := NA]
#clean up idx
dt[, `:=` (idx_Parent = NULL, idx_Sub = NULL)]
#report values
dt
#>    Parent_Product Sub_Product Sub_Product1 Value
#> 1:              A         red            1   100
#> 2:           <NA>        <NA>            2   200
#> 3:           <NA>        blue            3   300
#> 4:              B      yellow            4   400
#> 5:           <NA>        pink            5   500
#> 6:           <NA>        <NA>            6   600
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Re fewer steps, I think rowid works: `dt[rowid(Parent_Product, Sub_Product) != 1, Sub_Product := NA]; dt[rowid(Parent_Product) != 1, Parent_Product := NA]`

Comment: @Frank - neat trick. I've been using `data.table` since it first came out and wasn't familiar with `rowid`! Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a combination of [alistaire's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602710/how-can-i-transfer-to-a-tableau-format-in-r#comment96002934_54602710) and [Frank's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602710/how-can-i-transfer-to-a-tableau-format-in-r#comment96020711_54602896) suggestions:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {x[rowid(rleid(x)) > 1] <- NA; x})]
```

> ```
>    Parent_Product Sub_Product Sub_Product1 Value
> 1:              A         red            1   100
> 2:           <NA>        <NA>            2   200
> 3:           <NA>        blue            3   300
> 4:              B      yellow            4   400
> 5:           <NA>        pink            5   500
> 6:           <NA>        <NA>            6   600
> 7:              C         red            1   100
> 8:           <NA>        <NA>            2    NA
> ```

Note that the second streak of `"red"` values in column `Sub_Product` is handled correctly (as opposed to `duplicated()`).

To make the visual effect much more standing out we can use `""` instead of `NA`:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {x[rowid(rleid(x)) > 1] <- ""; x})]
```

> ```
>    Parent_Product Sub_Product Sub_Product1 Value
> 1:              A         red            1   100
> 2:                                       2   200
> 3:                       blue            3   300
> 4:              B      yellow            4   400
> 5:                       pink            5   500
> 6:                                       6   600
> 7:              C         red            1   100
> 8:                                       2
> ```

Unfortunately, this turns any repeating values in a streak of successive values to `NA` (or "", resp.) *in all columns*. For production use we probably want to control which columns should be included, e.g., only the second column

```
cols <- "Sub_Product"   # apply to second column for demonstration
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {x[rowid(rleid(x)) > 1] <- ""; x}), .SDcols = cols][]
```

> ```
>    Parent_Product Sub_Product Sub_Product1 Value
> 1:              A         red            1   100
> 2:              A                        2   200
> 3:              A        blue            3   300
> 4:              B      yellow            4   400
> 5:              B        pink            5   500
> 6:              B                        6   600
> 7:              C         red            1   100
> 8:              C                        2   100
> ```

#### Data

OP's data have been extended to include a `Parent_Product` `"C"` with a *second* streak of `"red"` values in `Sub_Product`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("
Parent_Product Sub_Product Sub_Product1 Value
             A         red            1   100
             A         red            2   200
             A        blue            3   300
             B      yellow            4   400
             B        pink            5   500
             B        pink            6   600
             C         red            1   100
             C         red            2   100
")
```

Comment: `duplicated.data.table` as opposed to `duplicated.default` does handle your extended data correctly, fwiw: `dt[duplicated(dt, by=c("Parent_Product", "Sub_Product")), Sub_Product := NA]; dt[duplicated(dt, by="Parent_Product"), Parent_Product := NA]`. I like your rowid-rleid approach to handle each column independently (assuming sorting), though.